# Can't access my API for SQL Server (Error 500)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, authentication, curl

I am hosting a site on IIS (Windows Server 2022), and trying to implement a simple register-login system via simple ASP.Net Core Web API, but while I can manipulate database internally, I cannot do it externally, nor via the curl test commands.

In the event logs there is an error "Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided.", but the login is correct, when I try to run cmd `sqlcmd -S <my domain> -d UsersDatabase -U <userlogin> -P <password> -Q "SELECT * FROM users;"` - it works perfectly, so credentials seem to be working.

I tried to log extensively but no logs are even created, the code does not runs it seems?
Do I miss something stupid, did I deploy the app itself wrong, missed additional allowance for external requests or something?

Here is my current class of the API:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using BCrypt.Net;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Serilog.Core;

namespace APIInjector
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Login { get; set; }
        public string? Nickname { get; set; }
        public string? PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public string? Email { get; set; }
        public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserInputModel
    {
        public string? Login { get; set; }
        public string? Password { get; set; }

    }

    public class UsersDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public UsersDbContext(DbContextOptions<UsersDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<User>? Users { get; set; }
    }

    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/users")]
    public class UsersController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly UsersDbContext _dbContext;
        private readonly ILogger<UsersController> _logger;

        public UsersController(UsersDbContext dbContext, ILogger<UsersController> logger)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpPost("register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(UserInputModel userInput)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Register action was called");

            if (await _dbContext.Users!.AnyAsync(x => x.Login == userInput.Login))
            {
                return BadRequest("User already exists");
            }

            var user = new User
            {
                Login = userInput.Login,
                PasswordHash = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(userInput.Password),

            };

            _dbContext.Users!.Add(user);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok(new { Message = "User registered successfully" });
        }

        [HttpPost("login")]
        public IActionResult Login(UserInputModel userInput)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Login action was called");

            var existingUser = _dbContext.Users!.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Login == userInput.Login);

            if (existingUser == null || !BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(userInput.Password, existingUser.PasswordHash))
            {
                return Unauthorized(new { Message = "Invalid login credentials" });
            }


            return Ok(new { Message = "Login successful" });
        }
    }
    public class Startup
    {

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddDbContext<UsersDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddControllers();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Appsettings.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=<domain>;Database=UsersDatabase;User Id=<username>;Password=<password>"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Program.cs:

```
using APIInjector;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Serilog;
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.File("E:\\logs\\myapp.txt")
            .CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
            host.Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close the application...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilog() 
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

Tried to log, as can be seen, but it just shows that program starts and listens.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"Login":"testuser","Password":"testpassword"}' https://<domain>/APIInjector/api/users/register
```

returns just error 500 without any details, with that login error in the event logs server-side

Comment: 500 is an internal server error. CHeck the logfiles for more information

Comment: As said, the server-side event logs show the "Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided."

Comment: It seems possible (even likely) that the connection string or identity is being overwritten. I'd log at SQL server using extended events: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3214/use-extended-events-to-get-more-information-about-failed-sql-server-login-attempts/

Comment: @MitchWheat, it gave me: `WIN-Q492ECD7OCI .Net SqlClient Data Provider 5 Login failed for user 'NT Service\SSISScaleOutMaster160'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: <local machine>] 2024-01-22 07:45:58.1250000`

Comment: That error msg says the exact problem. "Login failed for user 'NT Service\SSISScaleOutMaster160'" that looks like a service account and may not be able to login as it.

Comment: @MitchWheat, it is an account created for the SQL through the SSMS in Security>Logins and given all the permissions atm. What should I use to login instead then?

Comment: Maybe it's trying to use Windows auth because of the structure of your username? Can you try adding `Trusted_Connection=False;` to your connection string?

Comment: @MateusZampol attempted, no reaction. Also tried to create a windows user with corresponding credential, was not recognized either. I'd be really grateful for some kind of an alternative for my method rn. That database part was reviewed and rewritten by countless tutorials multiple times and I still don't get why Windows Server is quirky with that.

Comment: Tried to switch to windows authentication fully, gave it administrator credentials outright, returns the same error(!).

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the right instance of SQL Server? Also, are you sure you are not loading Appsettings.Development.json?

Comment: In your Login method, are you missing an "await"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hosting Bundle Installer - that what was missing. After restart API started to react and tell the errors properly.
The error with login turned out to be a completely separate issue, coming from the database scaling service - it was not properly set up by me. The API itself was just not running, but after installing the HBI requests to the domain brought it to life.

Answer found in the thread [ASP.NET Core site not running on IIS, works fine from commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50597590/asp-net-core-site-not-running-on-iis-works-fine-from-commandline), that was not marked as solved for some reason.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
ConnectionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;
User id=UserName;
Password=Secret;
```

Comment: Alas, to no avail. It certainly connects to the server but fails to login.